# Dache "No reachable cache host exception"

Tags: dache

using the dache for the session state and for the caching. i get the error

[NoCacheHostsAvailableException: There are no reachable cache hosts available. Verify your client settings and ensure that all cache hosts can be successfully communicated with from this client.]
   Dache.Client.CacheClient.DetermineBucket(String cacheKey) in d:\Dache\Dache.Client\CacheClient.cs:951
   Dache.Client.CacheClient.TryGet(String cacheKey, T& value) in d:\Dache\Dache.Client\CacheClient.cs:137

I am using the default values for the Client Configuration in the web.config and default values for the Host Config file.

is there any other setting which i am missing?

Comment: Please upgrade to Dache 1.5.4 and let me know if the issue remains.

Comment: I have upgraded to the Dache 1.5.4 and i still get the same issue.

Comment: That is very strange. It's possible I have a bug in the session state provider perhaps. Anything in the Event Logs?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Dache 1.5.8 - it was an asynchronous communication bug.